# Error executing "SendRawEmail" on "https://email.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ses

I am using Amazon ses but i am getting error Please help me on this in laravel 5.2.My email and domain is verified on aws ses.I am attaching error screenshot please anyone help me on this.[image]

Comment: Is your email verified **in us-west-1**? SES has different regions, and the default is us-east-1. (I find it highly unlikely you managed to verify the `@gmail.com` domain, incidentally.)

Comment: Basically on aws i have verified my domai email i.e, email@domain.com and i am trying to send email to something@gmail.com then i am getting this error and for sending email i am using below code {$business = [];
\Mail::send('welcome', ['business' => $business], function ($m) use ($business) {
            $m->from(env('MAIL_FROM', 'verified email id from ses'), env('MAIL_FROM_NAME'));
            $m->to('myemailid', 'Subject');
        });}

Comment: Sounds like you're in sandbox mode. While you are, you have to verify the **recipient** email `codingbrains10@gmail.com` as well. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Comment: yes I am in sandbox mode.It means if i am in sandbox mode i have to verify each recipients?

Comment: Yes. Sandbox mode is for testing; this is one of its restrictions.

Comment: Thanks it's working

Answer (score 3):

In sandbox mode, both sender **and** recipient must be a verified email address.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

> We place all new accounts in the Amazon SES sandbox. While your account is in the sandbox, you can use all of the features of Amazon SES. However, when your account is in the sandbox, we apply the following restrictions to your account:

> - You can only send mail to verified email addresses and domains, or to the Amazon SES mailbox simulator.

Answer (score -2):

In sandbox mode, both sender and recipient must be a verified email address.

Comment: You should consider accept @ceejayoz answer's.